# Developing Spring based Restful webservice for enterprise level application and mobile application

Tags: database, spring, web-services, application-server, serverside-javascript

Need help in developing an Enterprise application which involves hundreds of thousands of notifications and calls to server. Client has mandated to use Java/Springs stack. It has 3 portals involving like mobile, Institutes and Admin which depends on web services from server.

1. Which type of Database we should prefer?(It should support Hundreds of requests and Should support Geo-Location based queries)
2. Which application server we should prefer?
3. Which type of server side scripting we should prefer?

How about should I go with this?

Comment: For the sake of your client's money and nerves and your rating, I warmly recommend you leaving that part of work to more experienced ones.

Answer (score 0):

1. You really should read the answers to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9809
2. One you know it or have anyone in your team who knows it. Otherwise [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) seems pretty good.
3. Once again you must choose one you're comfortable with... and look at Thymeleaf.

If you are really starting something from the ground, you really get known the [Service-oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) and build your solution around it.